# How to run Invoke-Sqlcmd in PowerShell script from Tidal

Tags: powershell, tidal-scheduler

I have a PowerShell script (test.ps1) that executes a simple SQL query via Invoke-Sqlcmd.  The script lives on a remote, file-share server.  Below is the script:

```
param
(
[string]$SQL_username,
[string]$SQL_password
)

Write-Host ('begin script')
$db = 'some_DB'
$server = 'some_IP'
$query = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM some_schema.some_table'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Username $SQL_username -Password $SQL_password -ServerInstance $server -Database $db -Query $query -QueryTimeout 60000
Write-Host ('end script')
```

When I remote to the file-share server with a Tidal user account, the script executes successfully and as expected.

I have a corresponding Tidal job that executes this test.ps1 script.  Here is the Tidal job info:

Command

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe
```

Command Parameters

```
-ExecutionPolicy bypass -File D:\some_path\test.ps1
-SQL_username "<SQL_username.1>"
-SQL_password "<SQL_password.2>"
```

When I run the script via Tidal, the Output screen in Tidal shows:

> begin script
>
> Invoke-Sqlcmd: The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program...
>
> end script

So, it's clear that whatever user Tidal is using to run the script, the user recognizes the `Write-Host` cmdlet, but it does not recognize the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` cmdlet.  How can this be?  And, how can I resolve this?  (I found that the Tidal user is NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, not the Runtime User specified in the Run tab of the job, which is the same Tidal user that I logged into the remote server as.)

Comment: The SQL module is not loading in the SYSTEM's PowerShell profile.  See http://www.jasonq.com/blog/2012/3-things-to-do-if-invoke-sqlcmd-is-not-recognized-in-windows-powershell.  You may need to set the task to run with a user account as I think maybe it won't be able to access the network when running as SYSTEM.

Comment: I think you're right.  I created a new PowerShell session using New-PSSession using another user account, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL module is not loading in the SYSTEM's PowerShell profile.  You will need to run something similar to the following before any `invoke-sqlcmd` statements:

```
# For SQL 2008
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

# For SQL 2012
Import-Module SqlPs
```

You may also need to set the task to run with a user account as it won't be able to access the network when running as SYSTEM.

Comment: Beware that `Import-Module SQLPS;` changes the current working directory to `SQLSERVER:\`, the SQL Server provider.  And, unless you specify `Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking`, then Import-Module will emit warnings because the SQL Server developers chose non-standard verbs.  These are both supposedly fixed with SQL Server 2016, but I haven't checked myself.